# XPath get closest ancestor that has at least one p tag sibling

Tags: html, xpath

Is it possible to do this by xpath?

I want to get the closest ancestor that has at least one sibling `<p>`.

Example:

```
<div>
    <p>...</p>
    <div class="Looking for this div">
        <span id="x"></span>
    </div>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

The closest element meeting the criteria (from span tag) is it's `div` parent.

```
//span[@id='x']/ancestor::*[self ???
```

EDIT: maybe this is a good direction

```
//span[@id='x']/ancestor::*/following-sibling::p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your xml looks like this:

```
<doc>
  <div>
    <div class="Not Looking for this div">
        <span id="x"></span>
    </div>

</div>
  <div>
    <p>...</p>
    <div class="Looking for this div">
        <span id="x"></span>
    </div>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
</doc>
```

This xpath expression

```
//span[@id="x"]/(ancestor::* [following-sibling::p | preceding-sibling::p])/@class
```

should output

```
Looking for this div
```

Comment: Jack - thanks! Btw.  you submitted the answer two times.

Comment: @Milano You're welcome.  I deleted the other one - don't remember posting it twice, but maybe I need more coffee...